# How to automatically update the updated date column on updating row in RedShift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift which has an UpdatedDate column of type timestamp. The column is defined as

```
UpdatedDate timestamp DEFAULT getdate()
```

So when ever a new record is inserted the date is stored correctly in this column. The issue is in the update case. In update this column is not updated. What I need is for UpdatedDate column to update automatically when the data in the row is changed.

I know we can specify the column in the update query, but I do not have control over the query and cannot add the column there.

I tried using `Triggers` but Redshift does not seem to support them.
Thanks for your time. Let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Since Redshift does not support triggers, I don't see any alternate except for specifying the column name in the update query. It will be interesting to see an alternate option.

Comment: No direct way of doing this afaik. You could use staging table with the same schema, and change update to delete-insert from staging, but you mentioned you don't have control over the query, so I assume you can't do that either. You can also make and ugly query over stl_query, and whenever you see an UPDATE statement, you manually execute a script that updates relevant records. It is possible, but you really shouldn't do it:)

Answer (score 0):

Create Staging table for this purpose.
Refer Upsert in Redshift:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-specify-a-column-list.html

During update statement, set update_ts = sysdate.